# target array of shape not match output of shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm training Unet in keras, appear some problem.

iamge:512*512 ,5*1channel 1*3channel  = (512,512,8channel) 6 image
mask:512*512, 6mask

```
data.py in traingenerator
            img_batch = np.concatenate(images, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 8)
            mask_batch = np.concatenate(masks, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 6)
            #mask_batch = np.concatenate(masks, axis=2) #(1, 512, 3072, 1)
        
            #y_int = np.argmax(mask_batch, axis=2)  
            #y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)  # Convert integer labels to binary vectors 
        
            yield (img_batch, mask_batch)
```

```
error massage
ValueError
A target array with shape (1, 512, 512, 6) was passed for an output of shape (None, 512, 512, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
  File "C:\Labbb\unet_mao0\main.py", line 90, in <module>
    train_history=model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=20,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
ValueError: A target array with shape (1, 512, 512, 6) was passed for an output of shape (None, 512, 512, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

I'm wondering if the axis parameter should be set to 2 instead of 3 in np.concatenate(masks, axis=3), but it still doesn't work.
and model.compile only accept 1d or 2d

Comment: Would you please add more info to your question so we can understand the problem, also provide your model summary to see your layers and your train_data and labels shapes.